# Catching KeyEvents Outside of Program

Tags: java, keyboard

I was wondering if there is anyway to catch a KeyEvent outside of my Java program. I know that using the normal Java, you can only catch KeyEvents that are inside your Java program. From what I have read about this on different forums, I think that catching KeyEvents outside your program is all OS based but i'm using a Windows 7 if that helps anyone. If anyone knows how to achieve this, please answer back and if you don't mind a link too a tutorial or an example would be awesome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Catching KeyEvents Outside of Program"*? What is your objective?

Comment: When I press "a" and my program isn't in focus it'll pick up the KeyEvent and will print out the character "a"

Comment: No, don't use Java as a key logger as it is built to be OS agnostic and thus somewhat removed from the OS. Use C, C++ or some other language that gets closer to the OS for this nefarious purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might help:

[Java Keyboard/Mouse activity (even outside of my app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490469/java-keyboard-mouse-activity-even-outside-of-my-app)

It's not an exact duplicate, because it just wants to know whether or not there have been key events, but it gives you a pointer as to what to do:

Use JNI.

---

In addition:

The code in the link in the question http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90 doesn't work in Windows 7/Vista,
 but there is a newer version:

http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

And this, I think (I haven't looked at it in depth) is a nice tutorial.

It has ALL of the code you need for this.

Comment: I understand the main concept of that but I think it's a little overkill. Didn't help me much at all.

Comment: Wait, but it is the complete source. It's everything you need, written out for you!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you added on to your answer. I'm gonna go study this for a while and see what I can do. Thanks